# Сопоставление в Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Всем привет. Есть столбец с датами начала действия кода и дней сколько проработал код, пытаюсь суммировать дату начала и количество дней. никак не получается.
Dateadd не работает, через суммирование тоже. Может знает кто как решить?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ruSO. Пожалуйста, приведите ваши попытки (запрос), чтобы сообщество могло скорее Вам помочь.

Comment: `startdate + INTERVAL duration DAY`

Comment: Количество дней разное, и поставить определенную цифру к сожалению не получается. Пробовал startdate+day*(interval 1 day), но выходит ошибка перегрузки поля